# Showing spotipy playlist in QML

Tags: qt, qml, pyside6

Im trying to do something I think is fairly simple, but I am missing something. I take output from a spotipy playlist request, make a list out of the names, and pipe it over to QML. The problem is that I cant get my QML to show it on the UI Ive created. I get the error `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`. Heres the code Ive got so far:

```py
# main.py
class ListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    TextRole = Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == self.TextRole:
            return self._data[index.row()]
        return None

    @Slot(int, result='QVariant')
    def get(self, row):
        if 0 <= row < self.rowCount(QModelIndex()):
            return self._data[row]

if __name__ == "__main__":
...
    scope = "playlist-read-private"

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

    data_list = []
    results = sp.current_user_playlists(limit=10)
    for i, item in enumerate(results['items']):
        data_list.append(item['name'])
        print("%d %s" % (i, item['name']))

    print(data_list)
    model = ListModel(data_list)
...
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("myModel", model)
```

```
// SpotifyWindow.ui.qml
...
    ListView {
      id: pythonList
      width: 400
      height: 200

      model: myModel
      delegate: Component {
        Rectangle {
          width: pythonList.width
          height: 40
          color: ((index % 2 == 0)?"#222":"#111")


          Text {
            id: title
            elide: Text.ElideRight
            text: model.TextRole
            color: "white"
            font.bold: true
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.fill: parent
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: When using a [QAbstractItemModel subclass in QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass), you should implement [`roleNames()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) in the model, and then initialize the properties using the [`required property`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#required-properties).